# Помогите сделать resize "помягче"... (Jquery(window).resize(); )

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня страница "скроллится" в нужное место при выборе меню, когда происходит ресайз или зум надо выставлять скролл в определённую позицию.

Так собственно вопрос (не знаю как ещё объяснить): `resize` срабатывет на `drag` (т.е. в реальном времени, когда именно тянут за окно, зумируют), а мне бы хотелось на `drag and drop`(когда уже отпустили)

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Mzk/

Comment: Вопрос закрыт переработкой кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function debouncer( func , timeout ) {
   var timeoutID , timeout = timeout || 200;
   return function () {
      var scope = this , args = arguments;
      clearTimeout( timeoutID );
      timeoutID = setTimeout( function () {
          func.apply( scope , Array.prototype.slice.call( args ) );
      } , timeout );
   }
}

$( window ).resize( debouncer( function ( e ) {
    // выполняем что хотим с задержкой 350мс (т.к. установили в 350 строкой ниже), либо 200 по дефолту
} ), 350 );
```